# Is this triangle possible to draw?

Tags: triangles

If the triangle must have the following sides:

DE = 3cm
DF = 8cm
EF = 4cm

And not taking into consideration anything about the angles. Is it possible to draw such a triangle?

Comment: No because |DE| + |EF| < |DF|

Answer (score 2):

We can not draw this triangle since
$$
DE+EF=7<8=DF
$$
In any triangle, the sum of the lengths of any two sides must be greater than the length of the remaining side.

Answer (score 2):

No. The triangle inequality $DE + EF>DF$ does not hold.

Comment: Care to explain th edownvote?

Comment: Presume it was because no details of effort had been put in. Wasn't me that downvoted so I'm guessing.

Comment: @SimonHayward I disagree. The right keyword is here, the right computation as well, and of course the right answer.

Comment: No idea in that case. Some people do seem to rush to down vote new users rather than explain.

Answer (score 2):

Take the 3 cm and 4 cm sides and hinge them together. Can you then orient them in such a way to fit an 8 cm side between them? No, you'll run out of room. The farthest that you can get the relevant vertices apart is 7cm. This is the content of the triangle inequality mentioned in the other answers.